# Jackrabbit-Oak: Delete performance issues

Tags: jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

When I delete a node with a larger subgraph ( < 50.000 nodes) in Jackrabbit-Oak it takes about ~45 Minutes to perform the action.

My questions are, is there anything to respect regarding deletion performance and why does it take so long?

Here is what I do:

```
Node nodeToBeDeleted = session.getNodeByIdentifier(session, uuid);
session.removeItem(nodeToBeDeleted.getPath());
session.save();
```

And also tried this one which seamed to be a bit slower:

```
Node nodeToBeDeleted = session.getNodeByIdentifier(session, uuid);
nodeToBeDeleted.remove();
session.save();
```

What i can observ in the logs, is a reindexiation in that proces which takes at least a considerable amount of time

```
IndexUpdate$IndexUpdateRootState$CountingCallback - /oak:index/nodetype => Indexed 10000 nodes in 21,42 min ...
```

Additional response from oak in the log:

```
DocumentNodeStore$4 - Pushing journal entry at r17624a6d743-0-1 as number of changes (146510) have reached 100000
```

I use Oak 1.6.20 connected to MongoDB 4.0 running on an i7 U6600 (2 Cores/4 threads, 2,8 Ghz base) with 16 GB of ram. Write operations are much fast btw. The nodes I try to delete where created in about 7 Minutes over rest with all the overhead which usually apply.

Comment: Why do you do the "save()" operation after every single node?

Comment: @JulianReschke In that specific case of the two examples its actually even one single node, if you will so. The Session.save() persists the deletion to the database, therefore I added it to the examples to be complete. The node which gets deleted in the example should stand for an node which has a subgraph of about 50.000 nodes.

Comment: Ah, sorry for not reading the question properly. Did you try a more recent Oak version for comparison?

Comment: No I didn't so far. Its the latest minor release (Feb 2020) and upgrading  to the next major release is not trivial, I still have hope to get this solved with the already implemented (and grown) version.